# React-Redux add new value to the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reduce

I am having a two step form in react. The first step of the form we ask some information to the user and then I add it to the state. The second step of the form I ask some more information to the user and add it to the state, so instead of appending the information that was asked on step 2 of the form, it overrides the state, so the state now only the info that was asked in the step 2 of the form. How can I add the have both the information together. When i try to ...state it gives me error as state is not iterable.

```
const infoReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'STEP_1':
        return action.payload
    case 'STEP_2':
        return action.payload
    default:
        return state
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out

```html
import { ActionTypes } from "../../Constant/ActionType";
const initState = {
  Auth: {},
};
const AuthReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.AuthUser:
      return {
        ...state,
        Auth: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default AuthReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

first, copy the current state data and add a new action payload as second parameter

```html
   case 'ADD_Data':
            return {...state,action.payload}
```

Comment: When i try to write it like like, the complier gives me an error. Unexpected token ","

Comment: Also getting the error as state is not iterable